# how convert .obj file in .h file?

Tags: iphone, opengl

"I am trying to develop a game like **fruit Slayer**. I have code of that but I want to replace fruit to our objects,how to create them in 3d ."
fruit 3d .h file like as :
**
static const TexturedVertexData3D GreenappleVertexData[] = {
{/*v:*/{0.896683, 0.257172, 30.407585}, /*n:*/{0.073519, 0.000000, 0.997284}, /*t:*/{0.307720, 0.987318}},
**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't! Period, no discussion.

Implement a parser/loader for your .obj file and read the model from that one. You can bundle files for iOS and Android apps.